# Can't click "OK" on RetroPie Emulation Station

Tags: retropie

When I boot up my Raspberry Pi with the RetroPie SD card, I reach a screen where I have to configure all of the buttons for the controls (Emulation Station). I'm currently trying to use my USB keyboard with RetroPie. I am having a little trouble selecting "OK" on the configuration options; can someone help me?

Thanks. -- Krishna

Answer (score 5):

You have to either configure all the controls, you can long press any key to skip the ones you do not want. When all are done, or skipped, you will be on the OK button. Then just press the Button configured as A. On a keyboard it is the X key by default.

Comment: The question is, how would I select "OK" once I'm done configuring all of the controls? Let's just say I'm finished with configuring everything and would then like to select "OK." This is what I'm currently having trouble with. @Ashley

Comment: Button configured as A. On keyboard I think it is X by default.